# How to interpret a singlet term symbol for an s¹p¹ configuration?

Tags: electrons, spin

I am interested in the $^1P_0$ singlet state of $\ce{Hg}$ ($\ce{5d^10 6s^1 6p^1}$).

I interpret this to be the two following electron configurations below, because for an $S = 0$ state the two electrons have to have different spins.

[image: microstates]

Are these two both a valid state? Do they both have the same energy? How would I tell if it's only one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two states you have drawn correspond to the (antisymmetrised) wavefunctions

$$\begin{align}
\Psi_i &= \mathrm{s}(1)\alpha(1) \cdot \mathrm{p}(2)\beta(2) \\
\Psi_j &= \mathrm{s}(1)\beta(1) \cdot \mathrm{p}(2)\alpha(2)
\end{align}$$

Neither of the two states above are valid, as they do not obey the requirement for indistinguishability. For fermions such as electrons (spin-1/2), this is achieved by making the wavefunction antisymmetric upon permutation of any two electron labels. However, neither $\Psi_i$ nor $\Psi_j$ obey this:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}(\Psi_i) &= \mathrm{s}(2)\alpha(2) \cdot \mathrm{p}(1)\beta(1)  \neq -\Psi_i \\
\mathcal{P}(\Psi_j) &= \mathrm{s}(2)\beta(2) \cdot \mathrm{p}(1)\alpha(1)  \neq -\Psi_j
\end{align}$$

The appropriate wavefunction is a linear combination of these states (and a couple more):

$$\Psi_\text{singlet} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[\mathrm{s}(1)\mathrm{p}(2) + \mathrm{p}(1)\mathrm{s}(2)] \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[\alpha(1)\beta(2) - \beta(1)\alpha(2)]$$

If you expand these you can see the constituent wavefunctions

$$\begin{align}
\Psi_\text{singlet} &= \frac{1}{2} [\mathrm{s}(1)\alpha(1) \cdot \mathrm{p}(2)\beta(2) \\
&\qquad + \mathrm{p}(1)\alpha(1) \cdot \mathrm{s}(2)\beta(2) \\
&\qquad - \mathrm{s}(1)\beta(1) \cdot \mathrm{p}(2)\alpha(2) \\
&\qquad - \mathrm{p}(1)\beta(1) \cdot \mathrm{s}(2)\alpha(2)] \\
\end{align}$$

You need four "simple" wavefunctions in total because you have to account for the spatial indistinguishability of the two electrons (hence need a linear combination of two spatial wavefunctions) as well as the spin indistinguishability (linear combination of two spin wavefunctions).